# jacorb Two-Way Synchronous Calls

Tags: java, jacorb

I try to implement java program based on corba and using JacORB. I have to use the Two-Way Synchronous Calls with the Static Invocation Interface (SII). I can't find anything about it on the official documentation of JacORB.

> Once a client has retrieved an object’s IOR, it can invoke operations
>   on the object exploiting either the static or dynamic invocation
>   interface mechanisms (SII and DII, respectively).

```
org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, null);
        org.omg.PortableServer.POA poa =
        org.omg.PortableServer.POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_referencpoa.the_POAManager().activate();
        org.omg.CORBA.Object o = poa.servant_to_reference( new serverImpl() );
```

I initilized the ORB and then ? Have someone some documentation ? simple example or explaination about two way synchrounous call and SII ?

Answer (score 1):

A good definition for SII is http://www4.cs.fau.de/~geier/corba-faq/sii.html

You could find a simple example with JacORB in the demo/hello subdirectory.

I would recommend asking questions about JacORB on the jacorb-developer list (http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html). The source code for JacORB can also be found on github (https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/)